# Why is the probability of a single value zero in a continuos pdf, yet it is not impossible?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, density-function

I've learnt that continuous probability density functions can't describe the probability of a single value in the support, but only intervals, and I know how it can be proved. However what still confuses me is the fact the even if the probability of a single value is zero, that value *can* actually be picked up, thus it is not impossible. How can we explain this?  Is it because the probability is not zero but in fact infinitesimal?

Comment: I think a wise approach is to see it as a **measure**. The measure of a single point is zero, but the point still exists. You can also think of it like flipping a coin infinitely many times and always getting heads. The probability is zero, but it's still kinda possible.

Comment: @A.S. You may find the explanation for [almost surely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely) of some use, although its opposite of "almost never" is what I believe you're asking about.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.That makes it much clearer! (Still a bit abstract, but I guess it is intrinsically so)